# How to remove the individual titles for each density plot and just have one title for the entire plot in julia

Tags: plot, julia

I have a plot looks like this. I want to remove the individual title and add a title for the entire plot.

[image: The current plot]

Here is my code for this plot.

```
plot(
size=(1200, 800),  # Adjust figure size (width, height)
dpi=300,          # Adjust resolution (dots per inch)
density(distances_work, label="Work", legend=:topright, alpha=0.7, linecolor=:blue),
density(distances_home, label="Home", alpha=0.7, linecolor=:green),
density(distances_shopping, label="Shopping", alpha=0.7, linecolor=:red),
density(distances_other, label="Other", alpha=0.7, linecolor=:orange),
title="Distance Distribution by Activity",
xlabel="Distance (meter)",
ylabel="Density",
linewidth=2,
xlims=(0, maximum([distances_work; distances_home; distances_shopping; distances_other])),
legendtitlefontsize=8,  # Increase legend title font size
grid=true,
gridcolor=:lightgray,
legend=:topright,
framestyle=:box,
```

)

Answer (score 1):

To get a title for the entire plot, use `plot_title` instead of `title`. The top level title will take up space from your plots, so you may need to adjust the title font with `plot_titlefontsize` or similar.

For a table of other less used attributes, see
https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_plot/.

Comment: Works for me, thank you!